# FFmpeg set playing buffer to 0

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, media-player

I'm using FFmpeg to play RTMP streams inside an iOS application. I use `av_read_frame` to get the audio and video frames. I need the latency to be as small as possible at all times, but if there's a bottleneck or the download speed decreases, `av_read_frame` is blocked. Of course, this is how it should work. The problem is that FFmpeg waits too much. As much as it needs to fill its buffers. I need to set those buffers to a value close to 0. Right now, I'm dropping buffered packets "manually" to get the latency at the initial value. The result is the desired one, but I'd wish FFmpeg won't buffer in the first place...

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.